# Unable to migrate extjs 3 to extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, compatibility, extjs3

I am migrating from extjs version 3 to extjs version 4. I have added the compatibility layer to my project using Ext 3 to 4 Migration Guide given by sencha.
To enable Ext 3 compatibility I included the following lines after ext-all-debug.js(extjs4).
      //compatiblity

I removed

```
  // Ext 3
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/external/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

I fixed below script error

```
  // Ext 3:
  Ext.reg('mycoolclass', Ext.ux.MyCoolClass);

  // Ext 4 (compatibility mode only, optional)
     Ext.reg('mycoolclass', 'Ext.ux.MyCoolClass');
```

Still getting following error in extjs-all-debug.js.

```
    TypeError: me.events is undefined
           event = me.events[ename];
```

what I am doing wrong ?
How to avoid this kind of error ?
Please anyone suggest to migrate existing extjs3 application to extjs4 with minimal code change

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ext.define` instead

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.MyCoolClass', {
    extend: 'ClassNameYouAreExtending',
    alias: 'widget.mycoolclass'
});
```

and make sure that you have done `addEvents("yourEvent")` for your events